# Primefaces ajax event contextMenu causes default right click menu to show

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, contextmenu

I have a fairly simple `<p:dataTable>` in which I list some person data. The users should be able to add and remove persons. However, I have an issue with setting the `selection` value.

Let me show you what I mean. Following is the `p:dataTable` as well as the `p:contextMenu` (context menu is defined after the table).

```
<p:dataTable id="personTable" var="person"
    value="#{model.getPersons()}"
    selectionMode="single" selection="#{model.personSelection}"
    scrollable="true" rowKey="#{person.id}" scrollHeight="200"
    disableContextMenuIfEmpty="true">
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" />
    <p:ajax event="rowDblselect" update="@widgetVar(personDialog)"
        oncomplete="PF('personDialog').show()" />
    <p:column headerText="Name" sortable="true"
        sortBy="#{person.firstName}">
        <h:outputText value="#{person.firstName}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Address" sortable="true"
        sortBy="#{person.address}">
        <h:outputText value="#{person.address}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
<p:contextMenu for="personTable" id="ctxPerson">
    <p:menuitem value="Delete" update="personTable"
        partialSubmit="true" process="@this" ajax="true"
        actionListener="#{personService.removePerson(model)}" />
</p:contextMenu>
```

Now, with this code, to delete a person, the users have to select a row with left-click. This updates the selection as needed. Then the user can right-click to open the context menu and delete the selected person.

What does not work, is leaving out the selection step with left-click. So if the user enters the page, right-clicks a row to delete the person, the selection is empty.

Now this isn't optimal. I did some google searches and found another ajax event: `<p:ajax event="contextMenu"/>` which does trigger update of the selection when right-clicking. BUT adding this ajax event causes the browsers default context menu to always show over my own (my own context menu does open, but is behind default one):

[image]

And this is what it looks like without the ajax event contextMenu:

[image]

I am looking for a non-javascript way to A) update the selection on right-click only B) not show the browsers default right click menu on the datatable.

Any help is appreciated!

---

I am on primefaces 11.0.0, as the newer version 11.0.6 is not available through maven repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed for 12.0.0: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/8376

**MonkeyPatch (just add to your application JS file):**

```js
if (PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable) {
    PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable.prototype.onRowRightClick = function(event, rowElement, cmSelMode, fnShowMenu) {
        var row = $(rowElement),
            rowMeta = this.getRowMeta(row),
            selected = row.hasClass('ui-state-highlight');

        this.assignFocusedRow(row);

        if (cmSelMode === 'single' || !selected) {
            this.unselectAllRows();
        }

        this.selectRow(row, true);

        this.fireRowSelectEvent(rowMeta.key, 'contextMenu', fnShowMenu);

        if (this.cfg.disabledTextSelection) {
            PrimeFaces.clearSelection();
        }

        return this.hasBehavior('contextMenu');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you perhaps expand on the "add to your application JS file"? I am not sure which file you refer to. My application is java based and has no JS file. I do have have a components.js file in the maven dependency under `META-INF\resources\primefaces` which seems to include the datatable part.

Comment: I seem to have it working. I have added the code in answer to `META-INF\resources\primefaces\core,js` at the end of the file. Additionally, I replaced the `onRowRightClick` function that was defined for `PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable` in `META-INF\resources\primefaces\components.js` (line 13, second occurence of onRowRightClick). With theses changes I created a new version locally and used that as dependency. After restarting the application I also needed to hit `CTRL+F5` as it seemed that the resources weren't correctly reloaded

Comment: Sorry usually in most PF apps you have your own lets call it "myapp.js" which you load after all other scripts where your custom APP JS code goes. If you plug this in there it would override the PF default method. as a "MonkeyPatch" since its loaded after PF loads.

Comment: Now that you explained it, it seems like a much better solution that creating a new dependency :D I have now created an application js file, added the code to it and included `<h:outputScript library="js" name="myapp.js" />` in my standard template head. Great work mello!

Comment: Awesome!  Glad to heat it and now you learned more about MonkeyPatching JS code :)